# Adjust the result of a boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

I need to solve this in boolean algebra:

$$B(A+(B'+ A)')$$

Here is my attempt:

$$B(A+(B'+ A)')=B(A+(BA'))=B((AA')+(AB))=B(0+AB)=B(AB),$$

and the result should be just $B$. Should I just decide what is the right result (because I see it depents on $B$) or can I somehow adjust the result so it would end up just with $B$?

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your chain of transformations. You're transforming $B(A+BA')$ into non-equivalent expression $B(AA'+ AB)$. So there is no way to adjust your result to end up with $B$.

One way to obtain $B$ using equivalent transformations is the following
$$B(A+(B'+A)') = B(A+A'B) = BA + BA'B = AB + A'B = (A+A')B = 1B = B.$$

Here we are using the following identities:
$$ A'' = A,\ (A+B)' = A'B',\ AA = A,$$ 
$$A(B+C) = AB + AC,\ AB = BA,\ A + A' = 1.$$